# PostgreSQL: JSONB; get the key name by path

Tags: database, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-14

I have a requirement, on given path, I need to get the key name of JSONB, for example:

```
'{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "age": 30,
  "address": {
    "street": "123 Main St",
    "city": "Anytown",
    "state": "CA",
    "zip": "12345",
    "data": {"a": "b", "c": "d"}
  }
}'
```

So given `$.address.street` will return `street` (if key exists, otherwise null).

I look in the [PostgreSQL doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-json.html), but didn't found anything that can give me this.

Any help please?

Comment: You link to the docs for 9.5.  Is that the (quite obsolete) version you are using?

Comment: @jjanes, sry, edited to version 14

Comment: OK.  Your string looks like a JSONPATH query, so now look in that doc at jsonb_path_query and it siblings.

Comment: @jjanes how do I check that jsonb_path_query  returns null (path not exists)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of doing this:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN jsonb_path_exists('{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "age": 30,
  "address": {
    "street": "123 Main St",
    "city": "Anytown",
    "state": "CA",
    "zip": "12345",
    "data": {"a": "b", "c": "d"}
  }
}'::jsonb, '$.address.street') then (select * from jsonb_object_keys(jsonb_extract_path('{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "age": 30,
  "address": {
    "street": "123 Main St",
    "city": "Anytown",
    "state": "CA",
    "zip": "12345",
    "data": {"a": "b", "c": "d"}
  }
}'::jsonb, 'address')) as t where t = 'street')
ELSE
    NULL
    END;
```